# How to access API on private ECS from web HTML on public ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, networking, web-applications, amazon-ecs

Is it possible to access Rest-API on private ECS directly from web HTML on public ECS?

Our team wants to expose an API to users(outside VPN) through public web pages while keeping the API itself inaccessible from public network.

In my opinion, in order to expose an API, either the api-ECS should be public or there should be some logic on the web-ECS so we can route the users' requests like "web page -> web backend -> api".

*Any type of link/submit on a web HTML will be interpreted by client browser first and not send directly from one ECS to another right?

Conditions are as follows:

- API is made private by inbound-rules. Users are to use the APIs by clicking buttons on public web pages.
- ELB led to api ECS is set-up to accept requests from web ECS.
- nginx and React resources deployed on web ECS.
- nginx, uvicorn, FastAPI deployed on api ECS.

Please point me out if I'm thinking something wrong.
If there's a way to implement a system like above cleanly, ideas are very much appreciated.(Otherwise I'd have to deploy FastAPI on both web and api ECS...)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "In my opinion, in order to expose an API, either the api-ECS should be public or there should be some logic on the web-ECS so we can route the users' requests like "web page -> web backend -> api"." That is exactly correct. "Any type of link/submit on a web HTML will be interpreted by client browser first and not send directly from one ECS to another right?" Also correct.